# How to make my Python code more time efficient?

Tags: python

The program I tried to execute has following problem statement:

> The program must accept N integers containing integers from 1 to N
>   with duplicates in any order. The program must print the missing
>   integers from 1 to N among the given integers in ascending order as
>   the output.

example :

> Input: **5**
>
> **2 5 5 1 1**
>
> Output: 3 4
>
> Explanation: The integers 3 and 4 are missing in the 5 integers 2 5 5
>   1 1. Hence 3 and 4 are printed as the output

My code :

```
def modusoperandi(n, t):
    if str(n) not in t:
        yield n 

n = int(input())
t = tuple(sr for sr in input().split())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in modusoperandi(i,t):
        print(j,end=' ')
```

My code, however, failed to pass all the test cases since it is takes considerable amount of time to execute for test cases with huge input[takes more than 500 ms which is the time limit].

I tried to compute execution time using *timeit* method. It is peculiar that when number of elements in tuple increase the execution time also increase for a given N. I prefered tuple over list since it is supposed to be more efficient.

Comment: As an aside, generators (such as `modusoperandi()`, since it uses `yield`) are generally slower than regular functions due to internal overheads in bookkeeping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to convert the existing numbers into `int`egers, then put them in a `set`; sets are very efficient for figuring out whether or not a given value is a member.

```py
n = int(input())
extant = set(int(n) for n in input().split())
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if i not in extant:
        print(i, end=" ")
```

Comment: Could you explain how converting numbers to int --rather than keeping as str-- and using sets over tuples/lists makes the code less time consuming?

Comment: Comparing two integers (as long as they fit the 32 or 64 bits of the platform) involves one assembly operation. Comparing two strings require looking at each character individually and moving to the next character.

Comment: Checking the presence of an element in a list requires looking at all the element in the list. Checking the presence of an element in a set requires hashing the value and checking one (or a small number of) elements.

Comment: What Jeffrey said, and also you won't spend time roundtripping `i` from `range` into `str()`s for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The key is indeed to use a set for checking the presence of expected numbers in the input string.  You don't need to convert the input to integers though.  You can do this the other way around by generating sequential numbers as strings.

```
nums    = input().split()
numSet  = set(nums)
missing = " ".join(str(n) for n in range(1,len(nums)+1) if str(n) not in numSet)

print(missing) # 3 4
```

For this particular problem, there is a slightly faster alternative to using a set because you can afford to create an array of flags with a known (and reasonable) size:

```
numbers = input().split()
present = [False]*len(numbers)
for n in numbers: present[int(n)-1] = True
missing = " ".join(str(n+1) for n,seen in enumerate(present) if not seen)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = '5'
i = '2 5 5 1 1'

def compute(n, i):
    s1 = set(range(1, n+1))
    yield from sorted(s1.difference(i))


for val in compute(int(n), map(int, i.split()) ):
    print(val, end=' ')
```

Prints:

```
3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You should think of the complexity of your solution (which is quite bad):

```
def modusoperandi(n, t):
    # Since 't' is a tuple, the complexity of 'not in t' is O(len(t))
    # This makes the overall complexity of this function O(len(t))
    if str(n) not in t:
        yield n 

n = int(input())
t = tuple(sr for sr in input().split()) # O(len(t))
for i in range(1,n+1):  # O(n) iterations

    # 0 or 1 iteration, but the call to 'modusoperandi' is O(len(t))
    for j in modusoperandi(i,t):  
        print(j,end=' ')
```

Overall complexity O(n * len(t)). This is not a very nice complexity. You'd like to have a complexity which is linear in the input. There are two ways:

1. Use a hash table to mark all visited integers, and `set` is such a hash-table. Unfortunately hash-tables have some shortcomings.
2. Since there are `n` entries and the numbers are in the range 1..n, then it is very efficient to use a characteristic vector `values_encountered`, in which `values_encountered[i]` is `True` if and only if `i` value was encountered. For big input, of this kind, this solution is likely to run faster than a set, and to consume less memory.

.

```
import numpy as np
n = int(input())

values_encountered = np.zeros(n+1, dtype=bool)     # O(n)
values_encountered[[int(i) for i in input().split()]] = True # O(n)
# Or:
# values_encountered[list(map(int, input().split()))] = True

values_missing= (values_encountered == False) # O(n)
values_missing[0] = False
print(*list(*values_missing.nonzero())) # O(n)
```

Comment: Based on `.nbytes` it appears `dtype=bool` arrays aren't packed though - it's one byte per value, even if you could be clever and pack 8 bools into a byte.

Comment: @AKX that doesn't surprise me. But even with lack of packing, this is over  30 times more compact than `set(range(n))`, and runs much faster

Comment: Cool! This naturally requires `numpy` though, which wouldn't be possible in OP's case (an online judging environment if I understand correctly).

Comment: @AKX I suspect that you are right. The point of the answer is to give another approach, not to spoon-feed. The same approach can be implemented with a regular list, without numpy, if one chooses to. Had it been C, this approach would have been much simpler than the one with `set`

Comment: Yep, was just pointing that out, not trying to downplay your answer at all – sorry if it sounded like that!